# Chance of receptiveness to ritual / placebo

Tags: placebo

I've been reading about how rituals (performed right before a task) increase confidence and readiness for the task, and improve performance by "dulling the neural response to performance failure" ([source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5452956/)), and that they work by triggering the placebo effect. This lead me to my question: what is the probability of a ritual to cause this positive effect on a randomly chosen person?

I didn't manage to find any statistics or useful numbers regarding what part of the population is receptive to placebo.

Comment: Are you talking chances of a 'ritual' to be an effective placebo (little literature available I guess) or the placebo effect in general (larger body of literature)?

Comment: @AliceD I'm talking about rituals, but given the option I'd like to know at least the chances of a person to be receptive to placebo since it would give an upper limit to the estimate of ritual's chances to be an effective placebo.